# Idiomatic Haskell-like iterate in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, function-composition

In Haskell, I can get an infinite list of sequential function applications by calling:

```
iterate :: (A -> A) -> A -> [A]
```

Suppose in scala I have `f(x: A): A`. Is there a function that will result in a stream of sequential function applications? Like `iter(f: A => A, x: A): Stream[A]`?

Comment: You mean like `iter(x => 2*x, 1) == Stream(1, 2, 4, 8, ?)` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's in the library already: [`Iterator.iterate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator$@iterate[T](start:T)(f:T=%3ET):Iterator[T])

```
Iterator.iterate(1)(_ + 1).drop(100 * 100 * 100).take(10).toList
//> List(1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 1000004, 1000005,
         1000006, 1000007, 1000008, 1000009, 1000010)
```

Comment: `Stream.iterate`, too.

Answer (score 5):

There is [`Iterator.iterate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator$@iterate[T](start:T)(f:T=%3ET):Iterator[T]) and [`Stream.iterate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$@iterate[A](start:A)(f:A=%3EA):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]) ([via Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536689/135978)):

```
Stream.iterate(1)(_ + 1)
```

Or you can write one yourself, using `Stream`:

```
def iter[A](f: A => A, x: A): Stream[A] = {
  val result = f(x)
  result #:: iter(f, result)
}
```

(Note that holding onto the `Stream` will cause a memoization issue [warned about in the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)). Using it is as simple as:

```
scala> iter[Int](_ + 1, 1).iterator.drop(100 * 100 * 100).take(10).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1000002, 1000003, 1000004, 1000005, 1000006, 1000007, 1000008, 1000009, 1000010, 1000011)
```

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment, so I can improve the answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as @Sean Vieira's, with more Haskell-like syntax:

```
scala> def iterate[A]: (A => A) => A => Stream[A] = {
     |     f => x => x #:: iterate(f)(f(x))
     | }
iterate: [A]=> (A => A) => (A => Stream[A])

scala> iterate[Int](_+1)(1) take 10 toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

And swap the position of `f` and `x` can help the compiler:

```
scala> def iterate[A]: A => (A => A) => Stream[A] = {
     |     x => f => x #:: iterate(f(x))(f)
     | }
iterate: [A]=> A => ((A => A) => Stream[A])

scala> iterate(1)(2+) take 10 toList //Don't need to use iterate[Int] here
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
```